# What is the meaning of the notation $P_\theta()$, where a probability has a subscript Greek letter?

Tags: probability, terminology, notation, sufficient-statistics

What does theta subscript imply in e.g. this case:
$$ P_\theta(T(x)=t) = 0 $$

Comment: It means that the probability is evaluated with $\theta$ as the parameter of the distribution.

Comment: I'm convinced this is a duplicate of an earlier question but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: It could mean several things. For instance, one alternate explanation is that under the probability distribution parameterized by $\theta$, $P(T(x)=t) = 0$. By parameterized I just mean the parameters of this distribution come from the vector $\theta$

Answer (score 5):

It means under the distribution $\theta$, the probability of that statistic $T(x)$ being equal to $t$  is zero. Another way you can write it is:

$Pr(T(x) = t | \Theta = \theta) = 0$.

Comment: I would rather phrase it as the distribution indexed by $\theta$, in the sense of facing a collection of distributions indexed or parameterised by a parameter $\theta$. And the conditioning representation only applies in a Bayesian framework so I would also avoid it.